# Reinterpret event_shape as batch_shape in torch.distributions

Tags: python, pytorch, distribution

Let's say I have a Gamma distribution

`q = D.Independent(D.Gamma(alpha, beta), 1)`

Where `alpha` and `beta` are the parameters vectors with dimensions `[n_samples, batch_size, d]`.

The distribution will have for shapes:

```py
print(q.batch_shape, q.event_shape)
>>> [n_samples, batch_size], [d]
```

the `D.Independent` wrapper class allows to reinterpret the batch dimensions as event dimensions (as done when initialising the Gamma distribution), but is there a way to do the opposite, that is:

**Is there a way to reinterpret event dimensions as batch dimensions?**

I know that I can re-define a new distribution, i.e

```py
alpha = q.base_dist.concentration
beta = q.base_dist.rate
q = D.Gamma(alpha, beta)
```

that will have the correct dimensions

```py
print(q.batch_shape, q.event_shape)
>>> [n_samples, batch_size, d], []
```

But that seems highly unpractical and inefficient.

Any ideas?

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing... did you happen to find a solution to this? Thanks! :)

Comment: I don't remember finding an answer to this unfortunately, but please let me know if you do :)